# Android mpandroidchart line chart with cut-off points

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I would like to visible some data in LineChart with mpandroidchart in Android. But the datas have cut-off points. How can I resolve this problem, and visible the cut-off points in the chart too?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Add an image?

Answer (score 1):

`LimitLine` is what you are looking for,

```
LimitLine line = new LimitLine(1013.25f);
line.setLabel("1 atm - 1013.25hPa");
mChart.getAxisLeft().addLimitLine(line);
```

Please check the [documentation](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis) for further details.

Comment: Ok, I can draw with this a line, but I would like if the lower values than a constant wouldn't draw on the chart.

Comment: Am i getting wrong, since you are the one controlling the chart data, you can do it by applying the cut-off on the data. Just modify your data according to the cutoff points?